# Trying to understand an apparent web tracking malfunction

Tags: cookies

I use Safari and Firefox.  Since Safari doesn't offer the cookie handling I prefer, I frequently invoke a separate tool to clear out most of the cookies.  Neither Kayak nor Google are on my exceptions list.  A couple of times recently, I cleaned out cache, local storage, flash, etc. to get rid of the so-called zombie cookies (while no webkit clients were running).  I was in USA when I did this.

In spite of this, every time I access a Google site, it redirects to google.es and every time I access Kayak.com, it redirects to kayak.uk

I understand about browser fingerprint, but I have occasionally changed a **few** things that affect that.  And even if that weren't enough, there is nothin to hint that they have identified me specifically.  I would expect that in the absence of any completely unique identifier, they would assume the country of the IP address(es), which for over four weeks have been Comcast and ATT.  (And various public WiFi sites.)

It's not log in—I don't have a login for Kayak and I never log in to Google unless absolutely necessary.

With kayak, I changed it (menu lower right corner of search page) to USA/dollars, but as soon as I go to another site **without deleting cookies**, when I come back, it's on UK/pounds again.

What might be the cause of this?  There are a **few** other sites behaving similarly.

Comment: Am I in the wrong site?  Most of the "similar questions" were about Git. (obviously not similar!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand it now.  Someone correct me if I missed something.

It was not cookies or tracking or HTML redirect.

It was the **browser** "remembering" that I had visited kayak.co.uk and google.es while over there and "fixing" the URL for me.